# Django - Choice Field None:

Tags: python, django

Estou com problema a para fazer um *choice* pois, quando ele passa pelo `form`, o `field` retorna apenas `""` ou `None`. Já se eu coloco `widget=RadioSelect`, ele retorna a numeração correta.

Model:

```
ORDER_CHOICES = (
    (1, "1° Prêmio"),
    (2, "2° Prêmio"),
    (3, "3° Prêmio"),
    (4, "4° Prêmio"),
    (5, "5° Prêmio"),
)

order = models.IntegerField(
    'Premiação', choices=ORDER_CHOICES,
    db_column='order', blank=True)
```

Forms:

class SelectPremiumForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
order = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SelectPremium.ORDER_CHOICES,
                          widget=forms.RadioSelect)
class Meta:
    model = SelectPremium
    fields = ['order']
```

Comment: Leonardo, não entendi muito bem o que você pretende fazer, mas se for pra apresentar um comboBox com as opções do *ORDER_CHOICES*, você pode só referenciar o seu *Model* no *Form* como já foi feito que ele aparece sem precisar escrevê-lo novamente, ou seja, a linha ```order = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SelectPremium.ORDER_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)``` pode ser apagada. Pelo que testei aqui, está renderizando normalmente no html... você consegue editar sua pergunta pra ser mais claro?

Comment: Sim em Radio funciona normalmente, coloca em Select não salva apenas renderia, não valida o campo sempre vem em branco.

Eu queria usar em modo Select que seria o Default do Choice. Mas infelizmente não vem dado algum.